# What regex can match sequences of the same character in a given set?

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression that matches a sequence of characters in a given set,say {a,b,c}.

For instance aaaaaa or bb or ccc etc.

I tried using
`(.)\1+` and `(\w)\1+` but it will also allow other characters which doesn't belong to the set.

Is there any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` matches any character but a newline by default and `\w` matches "word" characters, that is, letters, digits and underscore symbols.

To match only specific symbol set/range(s), use a character class. For `{a,b,c}`, it will be `[abc]`:

```
([abc])\1+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5Babc%5D%29%5C1%2B&i=aaaaaa%20or%20bb%20or%20ccc%20but%20no%20ddddddd.)

**Details**:

- `([abc])` -  capturing group 1 matching an `a`, `b` or `c`
- `\1+` - one or more occurrences (due to `+` quantifier) of the same character captured in Group 1.

Comment: This is all I need. Than you very much for the detailed explanation.